# Sencha touch - is it possible to store a large database on the client

Tags: javascript, html, web-applications, sencha-touch

I'd like to be able to store, not a massive amount of data but not a trivial amount either on the client.  Basically, I want to be able to use something like an SQLite database on the client side using Web technologies.  The application is a foreign language dictionary so I want this data to be accessible once the application has been downloaded.

Is this possible with Sencha touch or any JavaScript/HTML5 technology?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's several options depending on the target browsers:

- localStorage (has the advantage of being cross-browser back to IE8)
- WebSQL (deprecated)
- IndexedDB
- Application Cache (this is a stretch for data storage...but it /can/ be done)

All of these technologies have storage limits, some of which vary between browsers, and to complicate things even more, some will let the user choose to allow expansion of the storage ceiling.

I've used localStorage with good results, and using a JavaScript compression library ( http://code.google.com/p/jslzjb/ ), you can gain some storage advantage (though in my experience, not a lot. If you're at 5.5Mb with a 5MB limit, the compression might get you by, though)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is.  The only question is what type of data, but you can store anything.

If its a lot of text/object data you can use localstorage.  Not sure how large the dictionary is, but that might be a very simple solution.  You can download the dictionary to the client and then use [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)() to convert your data to text (a string), and the local store can store it and retrive it.

A link to help, with other options including a database option:
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/offline/storage/